# Gertting error of CORS and CORB for SSE event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sails.js, server-sent-events

I am working with SSE event, when i send request from client to server for connection,then get error like,"**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**"
I am using Sails on backend and react on frontend side.

Here are some code for reference.

Frontend:-

```
let es = new EventSource(`http://localhost:1337/api/v1/sse?user=${username}`);
```

On backend i also allow cors in config/security.js file

```
cors: {
    allRoutes: false,
    allowOrigins: '*',
    allowCredentials: false,
  },
```

Note:- If i disable chrome's security , then in new chrome window its works

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome --disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingAlways,CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_tmp"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution , problem was with sails cors configuration.

It should be like

```
cors: {
    allRoutes: true,
    allowOrigins: '*',
    allowCredentials: false,
  },
```

Comment: In production you'll want to configure it to only allow requests from trusted sources.